# Solving Laplace Equation with Fourier Integral

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-series, fourier-transform

I have a problem with using the Fourier integral for solving the Laplace equation.

**Problem**. Consider the Laplace equation under Dirichlet type boundary conditions in the upper half-plane
\begin{equation}
\left\{
\begin{gathered}
u_{xx}+u_{yy}=0,\quad-\infty<x<\infty,\ y>0\\
u(x,0)=\begin{cases}
1,&|x|<\pi\\
0,&|x|\geq\pi
\end{cases}\\
u\ \text{is bounded as}\ y\to\infty\\
u\ \text{and}\ u_{x}\ \text{vanish as}\ x\to\pm\infty.
\end{gathered}
\right.\notag
\end{equation}
We will use the Fourier integral concept to find the solution. ■

I can use Fourier transform and show that the solution is
\begin{equation}
u(x,y):=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\omega}\sin(\pi\omega)\cos(\omega{}x)\mathrm{e}^{-\omega{}y}\mathrm{d}\omega.\notag
\end{equation}
However, I **cannot** solve this problem by applying Fourier integral technique.
I could also solve some heat equations but I could **not** succeed with this Laplace equation.
Let me show you where I stuck.

**Solution**. Suppose that $u(x,y):=\varphi(x)\psi(y)$.
Substituting this into the PDE gives us
\begin{equation}
\varphi^{\prime\prime}+\lambda\varphi=0
\quad\text{and}\quad
\ddot{\psi}-\lambda\psi=0,\notag
\end{equation}
where $\lambda$ is the so-called *separation constant*.
Then, we have
\begin{equation}
\varphi_{\lambda}(x):=
\begin{cases}
a(\lambda)\mathrm{e}^{-\omega{}x}+b(\lambda)\mathrm{e}^{\omega{}x},&\lambda<0\\
a(\lambda)+b(\lambda)x,&\lambda=0\\
a(\lambda)\cos(\omega{}x)+a(\lambda)\sin(\omega{}x),&\lambda>0
\end{cases}\notag
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\psi_{\lambda}(y):=
\begin{cases}
c(\lambda)\cos(\omega{}y)+d(\lambda)\sin(\omega{}y),&\lambda<0\\
c(\lambda)+d(\lambda)y,&\lambda=0\\
c(\lambda)\mathrm{e}^{-\omega{}y}+d(\lambda)\mathrm{e}^{\omega{}y},&\lambda>0,
\end{cases}\notag
\end{equation}
where $\omega>0$ satisfies $\omega^{2}=|\lambda|$.
Now, consider the discussion on the separation constant $\lambda$.

1. Let $\lambda<0$.

   - $\varphi_{\lambda}(x)$ and $\varphi_{\lambda}^{\prime}(x)$ do **not** vanish as $x\to\pm\infty$ if $a(\lambda)\neq0$ or $b(\lambda)\neq0$.
   - $\psi_{\lambda}(y)$ is bounded as $y\to\infty$.
2. Let $\lambda=0$.

   - $\varphi_{\lambda}(x)$ and $\varphi_{\lambda}^{\prime}(x)$ do **not** vanish as $x\to\pm\infty$ if $a(\lambda)\neq0$ or $b(\lambda)\neq0$.
   - $\psi_{\lambda}(y)$ is **not** bounded as $y\to\infty$ if $d(\lambda)\neq0$.
3. Let $\lambda>0$.

   - $\varphi_{\lambda}(x)$ and $\varphi_{\lambda}^{\prime}(x)$ do **not** vanish $x\to\pm\infty$ if $a(\lambda)\neq0$ or $b(\lambda)\neq0$.
   - $\psi_{\lambda}(y)$ is **not** bounded as $y\to\infty$ if $d(\lambda)\neq0$.

Then, we have
\begin{equation}
\varphi_{\lambda}(x):=
\begin{cases}
0,&\lambda<0\\
0,&\lambda=0\\
0,&\lambda>0
\end{cases}\notag
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\psi_{\lambda}(y):=
\begin{cases}
c(\lambda)\cos(\omega{}y)+d(\lambda)\sin(\omega{}y),&\lambda<0\\
c(\lambda),&\lambda=0\\
c(\lambda)\mathrm{e}^{-\omega{}y},&\lambda>0.
\end{cases}\notag
\end{equation}
Therefore, $u_{\omega}(x,y):=0$ for any $\lambda$... ■

At this point, depending on the ranges of $\lambda$, I **cannot** figure out that $\lambda$ must be positive, i.e., the solution should be in the form
\begin{equation}
u_{\omega}(x,y):=\{A(\omega)\cos(\omega{}x)+A(\omega)\cos(\omega{}x)\}\mathrm{e}^{-\omega{}y}
\quad\text{for}\ \omega>0.\notag
\end{equation}
Should I consider a boundary condition of the form $\varphi_{\lambda}(\pm\ell)=0$ for $\ell\geq\pi$.

Answer (score 1):

The separation of variables problem is
$$
              -\frac{X''}{X} = \lambda = \frac{Y''}{Y} \\
                       X''+\lambda X = 0 ,\;\;\; Y''-\lambda Y=0.
$$
In order for the solution $X$ to be bounded for all $x$ it necessary to to have $\lambda$ to be real and positive. So, set $\lambda = \omega^2$. The solutions $Y$ must similarly be bounded. So,
$$
            X(x) = Ae^{i\omega x},\;\;\; Y(y)=Be^{-|\omega|y},\;\;\; -\infty < \omega < \infty.
$$
A general Fourier integral solution is
$$
    u(x,y) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}c(\omega)e^{i\omega x}e^{-|w|y}d\omega,
$$
and $c(\omega)$ is a coefficient function determined by the boundary condition:
$$
            \chi_{[-\pi,\pi]}(x) = u(x,0) =\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}c(\omega)e^{i\omega x}d\omega.
$$
It leads to the same place, provided by you use $e^{-|\omega|y}$.

Comment: I cannot see where we are using the vanishing property of $X$. It implies boundedness of $u$ and $u_x$ but how can we verify at the end that these properties hold for $u$?

Comment: @bkarpuz : The conditions are built into the fourier integral solution, at least for $y > 0$ as $x\rightarrow\pm\infty$; this is true of the property for $y$ as well. You can see these from the integral solution. If you Fourier transform the equation instead, then you these need conditions for integration by parts to work out.

Comment: @DIBP: 1. If I replace the last condition with $u$ and $u_x$ are bounded on the upper-half plane, would I get the same solution?
2. We can have $\lambda=0$ and $X(x)=A$ and $Y(y)=B$, which also yields a bounded solution.
3. See the original post, where I make (my first) discussion on $\lambda$. I can make the cortrect discussion if $u$ is bounded.

Comment: @bkarpuz : Your problem has a unique solution $u$ such that (a) $u$ is bounded in the upper half-plane, and (b) $u(x,y)$ converges pointwise to to the mean of the left- and right-hand limits of $\chi_{(-\pi,\pi)}(x)$ at every $x$. The other conditions are not needed. The other conditions stated are really not necessary. Boundedness in the entire upper half-plane is necessary because $u(x,y)+y$ is a solution if $u(x,y)$ is a solution; this is because $v(x,y)=y$ solves Laplace's equation and is $0$ on the boundary where $y=0$.